# Outlook e-mail signature - links get underlined

Tags: outlook

i'm creating a simple html signature for Outlook.

I'm able to create the html file. The received e-mail displays in Outlook correctly, however, if I open it in Gmail, all the links get underlined..

My code for the link is simple:

```
<a href="http://example.com" style="text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Arial'; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; color: #dd2020;">
   example.com
</a>
```

After receiving the e-mail and opening it in Gmail, I look at the code using developer tools. My code gets altered:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:11.25pt">
  <span>
    <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">
      <span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#dd2020;text-decoration:none;">
         example.com
      </span>
    </a>
  </span>
</p>
```

All the styles from my `<a>` tag are stripped and a `<span>` is inserted. Is there something I can do about it?
I tried to make the signature using Outlook-s signature editor, which produces a huge html file, but no success there also.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my updated answer? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this happening is that certain email clients interpret HTML differently. this is why you always need to inline your HTML. remove the class="MsoNormal" and replace it with inline styling.

For Gmail-client, you need to surround your links with a `<span>` tag for some reason. This will not change your design, it will just allow Gmail to interpret your CSS correctly.

There are dedicated websites for just this: see https://htmlemail.io/inline/ for instance.

Just to be sure, create all your styling using classes in CSS, then run it through a CSS-inliner tool.

Comment: I don't think you understood my post. The code, I am writing has inline styles, no extra classes. The other one with the span is produced by outlook/gmail. I don't know which one, but one of them messes up my original code.

Comment: This doesn't work. In Mac, Outlook app, there's no way to "remove classes". There's also no way to edit our own HTML. When we copy/paste properly inlined html into the signature box, it auto-underlines the links. Forcefully.

Comment: @KhomNazid It sure does. i've been doing it for years (On the mac client ).

Comment: @Joel when I enter my own HTML, it gets bungled.

Comment: There are a bunch of utilites for it (one which i've linked). Check what css-attributes are available in the email client you are targeting and run it through that? 